# PrestaShop MultiShops class name changing

Tags: javascript, php, ruby-on-rails, prestashop, multistore

I have 6 same shops but in different languages. Last developer(which not answering for me) created this theme and made "Free Shipping" image(Red one with a car) in the header on https://www.badetonnesite.de/, how should I display it in other shops/languages?

I know that in .de shop picture div gets `<div class="free_shipping_de"></div>` class name, but in others it is : `<div class="free_shipping"></div>`

I was looking in modules, in code files, but I cant find file to modify it. Maybe anyone can help for me with this problem? Where should I look and what should I do?

Thank you in advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the way the previous developer has done it, you should look in your translations, because the way he has done it is via

```
<div class="{l s='free_shipping'}"></div>
```

In your `themes/default-bootstrap/header.tpl`, line 98. Same goes for `payment_logo` and a few others. Which means that this div's `class` attribute will be obtained from theme's translations for the currently selected language.
So in your theme's translations (in your Back Office) you should look for `free_shipping` line and translate it for other languages.

I might add you're lucky he doesn't respond, because this is very poorly executed :) You should consider hiring someone to do it properly.

Also, you might want to instruct your server to forbid `directory index`, because right now it allows anyone to download the template files. Ideally I should be getting an error when trying to do this.

Comment: Thank you! U solved my 3 days trip around the code files and it was so simple to change it.. +rep

Comment: One more thing if you don't mind. How did you found the exactly same code and code line in my files? There is any inspector extension or something like that? @Eihwaz

Comment: No, as I said - your directories are open, your templates are free for anyone to download. Try navigating directly to a template file in your browser: it will download that template. Which is why I recommended to use `directory index` to prevent this kind of behaviour, your server should return `forbidden` when someone is trying to access a file directly.